# overWriteFile(java.lang.String[], double[]) cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String[])' - Java

Tags: java, append, overwrite

I am working on a project, and I am unable to proceed with it because of an error.

I am attempting to overwrite a text file, using a method to scan through two arrays that hold specific crypto names. For example, in the section of my code removeCrypto(), which is option 4, I would type in BTC and it would remove BTC and the corresponding balance from the text file.

How can I make overWriteFile(line) work with both double and String?

[shows what is located in my .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSCz2.png)

```
public class Main {
static Scanner userInputInt = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner userInputString = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner userInputDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userChoice = getUserChoice();
    switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            viewWallet();
            break;
        case 2:
            lookupBalance();
            break;
        case 3:
            newEntry();
            break;
        case 4:
            removeCrypto();
            break;
    }
}

// This method asks and returns what the user wants to do
public static int getUserChoice() {
    System.out.println("****************************************************************");
    System.out.println("****************************************************************");
    System.out.println("************ Crypto Wallet **********");
    System.out.println("****************************************************************");
    System.out.println("****************************************************************");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("(1) View wallet");
    System.out.println("(2) Look up the balance of a given crypto");
    System.out.println("(3) Add new cryptos");
    System.out.println("(4) Remove an existing crypto");
    System.out.println("(5) Update wallet");
    System.out.println("****************************************************************");
    System.out.print("Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5): ");
    return userInputInt.nextInt();
    }



// This method is called for user choice 4
public static void removeCrypto() {
    String[] cryptoName = readCryptoNames();
    double[] cryptoBalance = readCryptoBalance();
    String[] line =new String[cryptoName.length];

    System.out.println("What is the name of the crypto you would like to remove? ");
    String cryptoNameTBF = userInputString.next();
  //  System.out.println("Please enter the balance");
   // double newBalance = Double.parseDouble(userInputDouble.next());

   for (int i=0; i<cryptoName.length;i++) {
       if (cryptoName[i].equals(cryptoNameTBF)){
          // cryptoBalance[i] = newBalance;
       }
   }
   for (int i=0;i<cryptoName.length;i++){
     line[i] = cryptoName[i] + "\t" + cryptoBalance[i];
   }
  overWriteFile(line); //CONTINUE HERE - HERE IS MY ISSUE
}

// This method reads and returns the crypto names from the file
public static String[] readCryptoNames() {

    String[] temp = new String[100];
    int lineNumber = 0;
    try {

        BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\John\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
            temp[lineNumber] = (tokens[0]);
            lineNumber++;
        }
        myFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading crypto name: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    String[] cryptoName = new String[lineNumber];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, cryptoName, 0, lineNumber);
    System.out.println(cryptoName);
    return cryptoName;
}

// This method reads and returns the crypto balances from the file
public static double[] readCryptoBalance() {
    double[] temp = new double[100];
    int lineNumber = 0;
    try {

        BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\John\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
            temp[lineNumber] = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            lineNumber++;
        }
        myFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading crypto balance: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    double[] cryptoBalance = new double[lineNumber];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, cryptoBalance, 0, lineNumber);
    return cryptoBalance;
}

// This method adds a new entry to the file and at the end of the file
public static void appendFile(String cryptoName) {
    try {
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt", true)));
        wr.println(cryptoName);
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There is an I/O error when writing.");
    }
}

// This method takes all crypto names and balances and writes on the file from scratch
public static void overWriteFile(String[] cryptoName, double[] cryptoBalance) {
    try {
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt", false)));
        for (int i = 0; i < cryptoName.length; i++) wr.println(cryptoName[i]);
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There is an I/O error when writing.");
    }
    try {
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt", false)));
        for (int i = 0; i < cryptoBalance.length; i++) wr.println(cryptoBalance[i]);
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There is an I/O error when writing.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void overWriteFile(Object[] crypto) {
    try {
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt", false)));
        for (int i = 0; i < crypto.length; i++) wr.println(crypto[i]);
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There is an I/O error when writing.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but it does not actually remove the crypto from the .txt file. It simply runs, but does not remove anything

Comment: I was just fixing your compilation error. To overwrite your file you need read all lines and write the ones you want to keep (skip the one you don't want)

Comment: in this loop `for (int i=0;i<cryptoName.length;i++){
     line[i] = cryptoName[i] + "\t" + cryptoBalance[i];
   }` you are not filterting out the crypto, you are adding every line. You need an `if` inside this loop. Also the loop above it is useless. You will probably run into another issue where it will have null lines at the indexes you skipped